# Разбор строковой даты '2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z'. Поиск регулярными выражениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Есть переменная:

```
video_daysFromPublication = '2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z'
```

Необходимо извлечь год, месяц, день, час, минуты, и секунды.

Comment: Хоть кавычки добавляйте, а то непонятно и невалидно

Answer (score 2):

Парсинг через [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
import datetime as DT

video_daysFromPublication = '2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z'

date = DT.datetime.strptime(video_daysFromPublication, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
date = date.replace(tzinfo=DT.timezone.utc)

# Необходимо извлечь год, месяц, день, час, минуты, и секунды.
print(date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour, date.minute, date.second)
```

Парсинг через регулярку:

```
import re

match = re.findall(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).000Z', video_daysFromPublication)[0]

# Если нужно значения получить как числа:
# year, month, day, hour, minute, second = map(int, match)
year, month, day, hour, minute, second = match
print(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
```

Comment: `Z` означает UTC, поэтому можно часовую зону добавить:`dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=DT.timezone.utc)`. Не могу поверить. что до сих пор не стандартного метода, чтобы rfc 3339 дату/время распарсить.

Comment: @jfs, обновил ответ

Comment: DT это модуль, а не класс в моём комментарии, чтобы написать `import datetime as DT` а потом без дополнительных импортов, к примеру: `minutes = (DT.datetime.now(DT.timezone.utc) - then) // DT.timedelta(minutes=1)` (один импорт модуля, несколько классов в нём). Это дело вкуса какой стиль использовать (для сторонних модулей, практически всегда лучше имя модуля явно использовать. Для stdlib можно и конкретные имена в глобальное окружение вводить).

Comment: это было логично :)

Comment: если автор местное время хочет, то можно astimezone() вызвать, чтобы местные часы, минуты получить (демонстрирует чем установка tzinfo может быть полезна)

Comment: из [pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713155/5909792)? :)

Comment: на Питоне 3, часто достаточно только стандартной библиотеки, чтобы местное время из utc получить. [Convert a python UTC datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4563272/4279) (в общем случае pytz может помочь избежать ошибки в некоторых крайних случаях)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем dateutil - он пытается сам угадать формат даты/времени:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dtparse   # pip install python-dateutil

In [88]: dtparse('2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z')
Out[88]: datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 21, 14, 35, 18, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

если указан `TZ offset`:

```
In [89]: dtparse('2018-03-21T14:35:18.000-03:00')
Out[89]: datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 21, 14, 35, 18, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -10800))

In [90]: dtparse('2018-03-21T14:35:18.000+01:00')
Out[90]: datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 21, 14, 35, 18, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

Еще примеры:

```
In [91]: dtparse('1 December 2017')
Out[91]: datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 1, 0, 0)

In [92]: dtparse('Dec 1st 2017')
Out[92]: datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 1, 0, 0)

In [93]: dtparse('22.03.2017 21:46')
Out[93]: datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 22, 21, 46)

In [94]: dtparse('Mar 22nd 2018')
Out[94]: datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Для rfc 3339 формата и stdlib справляется. А в общем случае,стоит  быть осторожным с передачей времени в свободном формате в dateutil. dateutil не всегда как человек читает и может неправильное время молча без ошибки вернуть. [Timezone offset sign reversed by Python dateutil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31078749/4279)